# Select data from three tables where show all records in first table row wise and all duplicates of the other horizontally

Tags: mysql

I have three tables Employee, Department, and a table that breaks the many to many relationship between Employee and Department.  If I want to get all employees with their respective departments, employees appear duplicated, so I want to show all employees with their departments but present departments horizontally to remove duplicate.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_emp` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `tbl_dept` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `tbl_emp_dept` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `dep_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `emp_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(d.name) AS departments
FROM tbl_emp e
LEFT JOIN tbl_emp_dept ed
    ON e.id = ed.emp_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_dept d
    ON ed.dep_id = d.id
GROUP BY
    e.id;
```